# how to check that a list contains another list item in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have two lists like this.

```
Dim List1 As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim ListMatch As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

I need to figure out if List1 contains all items of ListMatch. How can i do this is VB.Net?

Comment: this link could help you: https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Not SmallCollection.Except(LargeCollection).Any`:

```
Dim containsAll = Not ListMatch.Except(List1).Any()
```

[Documentation of `Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method returns those elements in first that do not appear in
>   second. It does not also return those elements in second that do not
>   appear in first.

Since `Except` is a set method, it doesn't take duplicates into account. So if you also want to know if `List1` contains the same count of items of `ListMatch` you could use(less efficient):

```
Dim list1Lookup = List1.ToLookup(Function(str) str)
Dim listMatchLookup = ListMatch.ToLookup(Function(str) str)
Dim containsSameCount = listMatchLookup.
    All(Function(x) list1Lookup(x.Key).Count() = x.Count())
```